# How to block bad words upon form submit

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to Javascript, so bear with me. The goal of this code is simply to block the words "crap", "ugly", and "brat" inside of the textarea upon form submit. I want it so that, after the user presses submit, the bad words will star out (****). This is purely a practice lesson I've been assigned, so it doesn't need to have any real use.

The problem with this code is that, once you press submit, all the text in textarea disappears. Therefore, there aren't any words to block anymore.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bad Words Blocker Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        var buttonPress = function ()
        {
            var com = getElementById(comments);
            var filterWords = ["crap", "ugly", "brat"];
            // "i" is to ignore case and "g" for global
            var rgx = new RegExp(filterWords.join(""), "gi");
              function WordFilter(str) {
            return str.replace(rgx, "****");
        }               
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="badwords" method="post" action="">
    <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input id="formSub" type="submit" onclick="(buttonPress())" value="Submit!" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you define `str`?

Comment: Whoops. Well, there's one mistake. I'll fix it. It should be:   function WordFilter(str) {
                return str.replace(rgx, "****");
            }

Comment: You can edit your question. Your current code makes no sense at all.

Comment: Still doesn't work, though.

Comment: Sorry. Noob to JS. How would you write it?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4517530/1282023) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1144788/1282023) should get you started.

Comment: Don't forget that client-side checks can *always* be bypassed — you should make sure that you check the same things on the server if you really care.

Comment: [Good luck with that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6099598/471272)!

Answer (score 4):

It's good practice to breakdown actions to functions.

```
var button = document.getElementById('formSub');

function replaceWords(event) {
    //Prevent form submission to server 
    event.preventDefault();
    var commentContent = document.getElementById('comments');
    var badWords = ["crap", "ugly", "brat", "basterddouch"];
    var censored = censore(commentContent.value, badWords);
    commentContent.value = censored;
}

function censore(string, filters) {
    // "i" is to ignore case and "g" for global "|" for OR match
    var regex = new RegExp(filters.join("|"), "gi");
    return string.replace(regex, function (match) {
        //replace each letter with a star
        var stars = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
            stars += '*';
        }
        return stars;
    });

}

button.addEventListener('click', replaceWords);
```

#### You can see a working example here ==> [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/QZW7K/2/)

Comment: Thanks, both of you! I didn't know I had so many problems with it—thanks!

Comment: @denomales trying to keep it clean ;)

Comment: This code is susceptible to the [Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Comment: @JanDvorak Thank you for an extremely interesting link. It would be interesting to see how many words are actually susceptible. I wanted it to be ****hole but on the other I don't want false positives

Comment: for one, there is the game of [craps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craps). Also, there's a [small village on the Prince Edward Island](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crapaud,_Prince_Edward_Island) and also a [genus of fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crappie). Banning [ugly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugly) is probably a bad idea altogether. Not to mention "lab rat" is sometimes written without the space and also there used to be a [guy with that name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunash_ben_Labrat). Oh, I forgot about the [capital of Slovakia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bratislava). Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

```
var my = "You son of a bitch.You are fool . www.google.com";
var badWord = /crap|ugly|brat|fool|fuck|fucking|f\*cking|f\*ck|bitch|b\*tch|shit|sh\*t|fool|dumb|couch potato|arse|arsehole|asshole|\*ssh\*l\*|\*\*\*\*|c\*ck|\*\*\*\*sucker|c\*cks\*ck\*r|\*\*\*\*|c\*nt|dickhead|d\*c\*h\*a\*|\*\*\*\*|f\*c\*|\*\*\*\*wit|f\*ckw\*t|fuk|f\*k|fuking|f\*k\*ng|mother\*\*\*\*er|m\*th\*rf\*ck\*r|\*\*\*\*\*\*|n\*gg\*r|pussy|p\*ssy|\*\*\*\*|sh\*t|wanker|w\*nk\*r|wankers|w\*nk\*rs|whore|wh\*r\*|slag| sl\*g|\*\*\*\*\*|b\*tch|f u c k|f\*c\*|b.i.t.c.h|b\*tch|d-i-c-k|d\*\*\*/gi;
my = my.replace(badWord,"****");
alert(my);
```

Use the above code with in java script block. For more java script based regular expression. Check out the regexp library https://github.com/javaquery/regexp

Edit:
Add your bad words in the regular expression. Followed by `|` (or)

Comment: This code is susceptible to the [Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Answer (score 0):

you should call the `WordFilter()` function

also you should catch onSubmit event of form, not click of button

and you called `getElementById` the wrong way

and the regexp was made incorrectly :)

so the code should be something like this (it works, i've tested):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bad Words Blocker Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        var buttonPress = function ()
        {
            var com = document.getElementById('comments');
            var filterWords = ["crap", "ugly", "brat"];
            // "i" is to ignore case and "g" for global
            var rgx = new RegExp("("+filterWords.join("|")+")", "gi");
            com.value = com.value.replace(rgx, "****");

            // change this to 'return true;' when you will be sure that all your bad words are catched and the form is ready to be submitted
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="badwords" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return buttonPress();">
    <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input id="formSub" type="submit" value="Submit!" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code is susceptible to the [Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).