# How do I add a filter to avoid the using of bad words?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I would like to add to this chat system a function which should avoid foul language. I already tried to implement the following code: [How to block bad words upon form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384992/how-to-block-bad-words-upon-form-submit)

But it didn't work for me, and maybe I didn't put it to the right position. 
The bad words should get changed to a star word before the message before the message is put into the database.

Could someone please help me with the code and tell me what I could do?

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
?>
<?php
 exit; 
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Chat Box</title>

    <!-- Mobile Optimation -->
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chat.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

function submitChat(){
  if(form1.msg.value == ''){
    alert('Enter your message!');
    return;
   }
   $('#imageload').show();
   var msg = form1.msg.value;
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200){
       document.getElementById('chatlogs').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
       $('#imageload').hide();
      }
    }
   xmlhttp.open('GET','insert.php?msg='+msg,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
 
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
  setInterval(function() {$('#chatlogs').load('logs.php');}, 2000);
    });

function pageScroll(){
 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
}

window.onload = function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
 }, 4000);
};

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<div class="header_platz"></div>
<img src="png/home-50.png" class="header_home">
<span class="part_name">Globalchat</span>
<a href="info.php"><img src="png/info-50.png" class="header_info"></a>
<span class="loggedin">Logged in as: <b><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></b></span>
</div>

<div id="imageload" style="display:none;">
<img src="1-0.gif" />
</div>

<div id="chatlogs">
LOADING CHATLOGS PLEASE WAIT... <img src="1-0.gif" />
</div>

<div class="chatbox">
<form name="form1">
<input name="msg" id="mes_msg" class="boxformal boxformal-cf" required placeholder="Message"></input>
<input type="submit" style="visibility:hidden" onClick="submitChat();pageScroll()" class="button"></input>
<a href="#" onClick="submitChat();pageScroll()" class="button">Send</a>
</form>

</div>

</body>
```

**EDIT:**
OK, this is the insert.php script:

@Jonathan Kuhn

```html
<?php
session_start();
$uname = $_SESSION['username'];
$msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "--", "--");
mysql_select_db('chat',$con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO logs (`username` , `msg`) VALUES ('$uname','$msg')");

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id ASC");

while($extract = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
  echo "<span class='uname'>" . $extract['username'] . "</span>: <span class='msg'>" . $extract['msg'] . "</span><br>";
 }

?>
```

Comment: Where do you have any of that bad-word-star code? because I'm not seeing it at all. Also, I would avoid doing that in javascript and check it server side in php (`insert.php`) else it is easily bypassed.

Comment: It's typically as simple as `= preg_replace("/\b(please help me|bad words)\b/i", "***", $msg);`

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn How can I do this in php? Should I post the insert.php script?

Comment: @mario and where do i put the bad words? and where the code snippet?

Comment: given you're loading jquery, why are you doing a manual ajax request? all that xmlhttprequest stuff is essentially pointless.

Comment: If you post `insert.php` and tag me I'll help with setting up some sort of simple filtering on the php side.

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn I put the insert.php file now into the main question above. Thanks for helping btw :)

Comment: @Intera please note, php mysql extension is highly deprecated. please use the mysqli or PDO ones. Additional, have a look at mysql injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the new `insert.php`. I added the badword filter, switched it over to using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (which will prevent sql injection) and secured it a little.

```
<?php
session_start();
$uname = $_SESSION['username'];
$msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "chat");
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die("Unable to connect to database: " . $db->connect_error);
}

//the list of words to check.
$badWordList = array(
    'test1',
    'test2'
    );

//loop over each bad word
foreach($badWordList as $k=>$bad){
    //clean up the bad word for use in a regex
    $pattern = '/\b'.preg_quote($bad).'\b/i';

    //replace each bad word
    $msg = preg_replace($pattern, str_repeat('*', strlen($bad)), $msg);
}

//call html entities to prevent html from being entered
$msg = htmlentities($msg, ENT_QUOTES);

//create a prepared statement
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO logs (`username` , `msg`) VALUES (?,?)");

//bind the username and message
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $uname, $msg);

//run the query to insert the row
$stmt->execute();

//get all the entries from `logs`
if($result = $db->query("SELECT `username`,`msg` FROM `logs` ORDER by `id` ASC")){
    //loop over the result and echo out the chat
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<span class='uname'>" . $row['username'] . "</span>: <span class='msg'>" . $row['msg'] . "</span><br>";
    }
} else {
    die("There was an error retrieving the chat records: " . $db->error);
}
```

Some notes:

- This will find bad words in a case sensitive manner so if you were looking for "foo", it will find "FOO" or "Foo" or "fOo".
- It is using a boundary match so it will match the whole word only. If you were looking for "foo", it would not match "food". Keep this in mind as it will also not match a plural version of a bad word. If you remove the `\b` boundary characters from the pattern then "food" will become "***d". Up to you how want to handle it.
- It is easy to bypass. You can substitute characters ("f00" with zeroes), put additional characters ("foooo") or do something like add spaces between letters ("f o o"). It won't catch any of those variations.

This is meant as a simple first line detection. Nothing will substitute having someone moderate the chat and taking action. You can make your filter more advanced but that gets complicated and the tradeoff from simplicity isn't usually worth it.

Comment: Well :) First **thank you so much** for your help!! But it seems there's a problem ... It says it couldn't connect to the database, of course I changed the password and username. I also have logs.php which is not using mysqli yet, maybe this is the problem? Do you know why it might be unable to connect to the database? /: BTW there will be mods in the chat.

Comment: If they are separate scripts, using mysql in one and mysqli in the other won't make a difference. You really should switch the other script to mysqli though and prepare/bind your queries (unless you like getting hacked). Is it showing an error message?

Comment: Yes. 'Unable to connect to database:'

Comment: Oops, found it. Change `$db->connect_errno >= 0` to be just `>`. It will return `0` if there was no error so we want to check if it is greater than zero. I don't have a system to test this on so I wrote it without testing and might have made a small mistake like that somewhere else too. Updated the code.

Comment: Ok, now there is no more connection problem :) But the bad words don't get replaced by stars ... What could I do to solve this?

Comment: Doh: `preg_replace($pattern, '***', $msg);` should be `$msg = preg_replace($pattern, '***', $msg);`. Updated code.

Comment: Just optinal .. Is there a way to show as many stars as the number of letters of the word?

Comment: Updated code. Just change `'***'` to `str_repeat('*', strlen($bad))`

Comment: Ok changed it also in my script now. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score -1):

```
//before send

var regex = /\b(please help me|bad words)\b/i;

msg = msg .replace(regex,  "***");

//finally
```

Comment: And where do I put the list of the bad words there? And where should I put this code?

Comment: before .open() and replace it like 'please help me|bad words'  to 'badowrd1|badword2|..'  , but thing there are still better ways to do that

Comment: Use should do that on PHP so nobody can read the bad owrd list from the page source, use preg_replace() like mario sayed above, $msg ist then$_REQUEST['msg'];

Comment: $_REQUEST['msg']; in insert.php

Comment: I thing you have to go way deeper into this, because thing of the possiblitily of using something like t*ht in a message .... or th's, look for an api in php or js or block all non 0-9 and a-zA-Z