# Profanity Regex not working

Tags: c#, regex

The error

> Not enough )'s.

The regex profanity string

```
"[^!@#$%^&*]*(ahole|anus|ash0le|ash0les|asholes|ass|Ass Monkey|Assface|assh0le|assh0lez|asshole|assholes|assholz|asswipe|azzhole|bassterds|bastard|bastards|bastardz|basterds|basterdz|Biatch|bitch|bitches|Blow Job|boffing|butthole|buttwipe|c0ck|c0cks|c0k|Carpet Muncher|cawk|cawks|Clit|cnts|cntz|cock|cockhead|cock-head|cocks|CockSucker|cock-sucker|crap|cum|cunt|cunts|cuntz|dick|dild0|dild0s|dildo|dildos|dilld0|dilld0s|dominatricks|dominatrics|dominatrix|dyke|enema|f u c k|f u c k e r|fag|fag1t|faget|fagg1t|faggit|faggot|fagit|fags|fagz|faig|faig|fart|flipping the bird|fuck|fucker|fuckin|fucking|fucks|Fudge Packer|fuk|Fukah|Fuken|fuker|Fukin|Fukk|Fukkah|Fukken|Fukker|Fukkin|g00k|gay|gayboy|gaygirl|gays|gayz|God-damned|h00r|h0ar|h0re|hells|hoar|hoor|hoore|jackoff|jap|japs|jerk-off|jisim|jiss|jizm|jizz|knob|knobs|knobz|kunt|kunts|kuntz|Lesbian|Lezzian|Lipshits|Lipshitz|masochist|masokist|massterbait|masstrbait|masstrbate|masterbaiter|masterbate|masterbates|Motha Fucker|Motha Fuker|Motha Fukkah|Motha Fukker|Mother Fucker|Mother Fukah|Mother Fuker|Mother Fukkah|Mother Fukker|mother-fucker|Mutha Fucker|Mutha Fukah|Mutha Fuker|Mutha Fukkah|Mutha Fukker|n1gr|nastt|nigger;|nigur;|niiger;|niigr;|orafis|orgasim;|orgasm|orgasum|oriface|orifice|orifiss|packi|packie|packy|paki|pakie|paky|pecker|peeenus|peeenusss|peenus|peinus|pen1s|penas|penis|penis-breath|penus|penuus|Phuc|Phuck|Phuk|Phuker|Phukker|polac|polack|polak|Poonani|pr1c|pr1ck|pr1k|pusse|pussee|pussy|puuke|puuker|queer|queers|queerz|qweers|qweerz|qweir|recktum|rectum|retard|sadist|scank|schlong|screwing|semen|sex|sexy|Sh!t|sh1t|sh1ter|sh1ts|sh1tter|sh1tz|shit|shits|shitter|Shitty|Shity|shitz|Shyt|Shyte|Shytty|Shyty|skanck|skank|skankee|skankey|skanks|Skanky|slut|sluts|Slutty|slutz|son-of-a-bitch|tit|turd|va1jina|vag1na|vagiina|vagina|vaj1na|vajina|vullva|vulva|w0p|wh00r|wh0re|whore|xrated|xxx|b!+ch|bitch|blowjob|clit|arschloch|fuck|shit|ass|asshole|b!tch|b17ch|b1tch|bastard|bi+ch|boiolas|buceta|c0ck|cawk|chink|cipa|clits|cock|cum|cunt|dildo|dirsa|ejakulate|fatass|fcuk|fuk|fux0r|hoer|hore|jism|kawk|l3itch|l3i+ch|lesbian|masturbate|masterbat|masterbat3|motherfucker|s.o.b.|mofo|nazi|nigga|nigger|nutsack|phuck|pimpis|pusse|pussy|scrotum|sh!t|shemale|shi+|sh!+|slut|smut|teets|tits|boobs|b00bs|teez|testical|testicle|titt|w00se|jackoff|wank|whoar|whore|damn|dyke|fuck|shit|@$$|amcik|andskota|arse|assrammer|ayir|bi7ch|bitch|bollock|breasts|butt-pirate|cabron|cazzo|chraa|chuj|Cock|cunt|d4mn|daygo|dego|dick|dike|dupa|dziwka|ejackulate|Ekrem|Ekto|enculer|faen|fag|fanculo|fanny|feces|feg|Felcher|ficken|fitt|Flikker|foreskin|Fotze|Fu(|fuk|futkretzn|gay|gook|guiena|h0r|h4x0r|hell|helvete|hoer|honkey|Huevon|hui|injun|jizz|kanker|kike|klootzak|kraut|knulle|kuk|kuksuger|Kurac|kurwa|kusi|kyrpa|lesbo|mamhoon|masturbat|merd|mibun|monkleigh|mouliewop|muie|mulkku|muschi|nazis|nepesaurio|nigger|orospu|paska|perse|picka|pierdol|pillu|pimmel|piss|pizda|poontsee|poop|porn|p0rn|pr0n|preteen|pula|pule|puta|puto|qahbeh|queef|rautenberg|schaffer|scheiss|schlampe|schmuck|screw|sh!t|sharmuta|sharmute|shipal|shiz|skribz|skurwysyn|sphencter|spic|spierdalaj|splooge|suka|b00b|testicle|titt|twat|vittu|wank|wetback|wichser|wop|yed|zabourah)[^!@#$%^&*]*"
```

This is the method that blows up

```
 public string FilterWords(string inputWords)
 {
    Regex wordFilter = new Regex(ProfanityBlackList); //Blows up on this line
    return wordFilter.Replace(inputWords, "!#@!$%");
 }
```

I can't figure out why this isn't working. I have an even amount of parens

Comment: Related: [Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](http://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/)

Comment: I do hope you'll make the actual code do a case-insensitive check by making it `new Regex(ProfanityBlackList, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`. Otherwise British place names such as Penistone, Assloss, and Cockfosters could inadvertently be allowed through.

Comment: Fortunately, it correctly censors other British place names such as Scunthorpe, Stow cum Quy, and Lightwater. It misses Poole, though!

Comment: @JMarsch that's the exact issue im having now. But at least I can get my app certified once again.

Comment: After careful consideration, I think you missed a few...

Comment: I learnt so many new words today.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a paren hiding about 3 quarters of the way through the text

Also to filter a paragraph for the profanity and return the non profane text the chars need to be taken off the front and end.

Here is the working regex

```
 String ProfanityBlackList = "\s(ahole|anus|ash0le|asles|asholes|ass|Ass Monkey|Assface|assh0le|assh0lez|asshole|assholes|assholz|asswipe|azzhole|bassterds|bastard|bastards|bastardz|basterds|basterdz|Biatch|bitch|bitches|Blow Job|boffing|butthole|buttwipe|c0ck|c0cks|c0k|Carpet Muncher|cawk|cawks|Clit|cnts|cntz|cock|cockhead|cock-head|cocks|CockSucker|cock-sucker|crap|cum|cunt|cunts|cuntz|dick|dild0|dild0s|dildo|dildos|dilld0|dilld0s|dominatricks|dominatrics|dominatrix|dyke|enema|f u c k|f u c k e r|fag|fag1t|faget|fagg1t|faggit|faggot|fagit|fags|fagz|faig|faig|fart|flipping the bird|fuck|fucker|fuckin|fucking|fucks|Fudge Packer|fuk|Fukah|Fuken|fuker|Fukin|Fukk|Fukkah|Fukken|Fukker|Fukkin|g00k|gay|gayboy|gaygirl|gays|gayz|God-damned|h00r|h0ar|h0re|hells|hoar|hoor|hoore|jackoff|jap|japs|jerk-off|jisim|jiss|jizm|jizz|knob|knobs|knobz|kunt|kunts|kuntz|Lesbian|Lezzian|Lipshits|Lipshitz|masochist|masokist|massterbait|masstrbait|masstrbate|masterbaiter|masterbate|masterbates|Motha Fucker|Motha Fuker|Motha Fukkah|Motha Fukker|Mother Fucker|Mother Fukah|Mother Fuker|Mother Fukkah|Mother Fukker|mother-fucker|Mutha Fucker|Mutha Fukah|Mutha Fuker|Mutha Fukkah|Mutha Fukker|n1gr|nastt|nigger;|nigur;|niiger;|niigr;|orafis|orgasim;|orgasm|orgasum|oriface|orifice|orifiss|packi|packie|packy|paki|pakie|paky|pecker|peeenus|peeenusss|peenus|peinus|pen1s|penas|penis|penis-breath|penus|penuus|Phuc|Phuck|Phuk|Phuker|Phukker|polac|polack|polak|Poonani|pr1c|pr1ck|pr1k|pusse|pussee|pussy|puuke|puuker|queer|queers|queerz|qweers|qweerz|qweir|recktum|rectum|retard|sadist|scank|schlong|screwing|semen|sex|sexy|Sh!t|sh1t|sh1ter|sh1ts|sh1tter|sh1tz|shit|shits|shitter|Shitty|Shity|shitz|Shyt|Shyte|Shytty|Shyty|skanck|skank|skankee|skankey|skanks|Skanky|slut|sluts|Slutty|slutz|son-of-a-bitch|tit|turd|va1jina|vag1na|vagiina|vagina|vaj1na|vajina|vullva|vulva|w0p|wh00r|wh0re|whore|xrated|xxx|b!+ch|bitch|blowjob|clit|arschloch|fuck|shit|ass|asshole|b!tch|b17ch|b1tch|bastard|bi+ch|boiolas|buceta|c0ck|cawk|chink|cipa|clits|cock|cum|cunt|dildo|dirsa|ejakulate|fatass|fcuk|fuk|fux0r|hoer|hore|jism|kawk|l3itch|l3i+ch|lesbian|masturbate|masterbat|masterbat3|motherfucker|s.o.b.|mofo|nazi|nigga|nigger|nutsack|phuck|pimpis|pusse|pussy|scrotum|sh!t|shemale|shi+|sh!+|slut|smut|teets|tits|boobs|b00bs|teez|testical|testicle|titt|w00se|jackoff|wank|whoar|whore|damn|dyke|fuck|shit|@$$|amcik|andskota|arse|assrammer|ayir|bi7ch|bitch|bollock|breasts|butt-pirate|cabron|cazzo|chraa|chuj|Cock|cunt|d4mn|daygo|dego|dick|dike|dupa|dziwka|ejackulate|Ekrem|Ekto|enculer|faen|fag|fanculo|fanny|feces|feg|Felcher|ficken|fitt|Flikker|foreskin|Fotze|Fu|fuk|futkretzn|gay|gook|guiena|h0r|h4x0r|hell|helvete|hoer|honkey|Huevon|hui|injun|jizz|kanker|kike|klootzak|kraut|knulle|kuk|kuksuger|Kurac|kurwa|kusi|kyrpa|lesbo|mamhoon|masturbat|merd|mibun|monkleigh|mouliewop|muie|mulkku|muschi|nazis|nepesaurio|nigger|orospu|paska|perse|picka|pierdol|pillu|pimmel|piss|pizda|poontsee|poop|porn|p0rn|pr0n|preteen|pula|pule|puta|puto|qahbeh|queef|rautenberg|schaffer|scheiss|schlampe|schmuck|screw|sh!t|sharmuta|sharmute|shipal|shiz|skribz|skurwysyn|sphencter|spic|spierdalaj|splooge|suka|b00b|testicle|titt|twat|vittu|wank|wetback|wichser|wop|yed|zabourah)\s";
```

This works perfect with the above method.

Comment: lol I had to implement a profanity filter in an app before it would certify. I hate this as much as anyone else does.

Comment: I think it was intentional to be `Fu(`, so you shouldn't replace it with `Fu`, but rather with `Fu\(`.

Comment: So you asked and answered the question by yourself.

Comment: @BugraCuhadaroglu I hardly would say it was by myself. I asked my co-workers and they were much wiser than I in the way of Regex-foo

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov excellent point. I have to clean it up tonight. I will fix that. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried testing it through these? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6099598/922184

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the parenthesis that aren't part of the regex capture group with a backslash `\`... but part of the expected input. E.g.:

```
^(?<my_group>\(.*\))$
```

For example, the group that captures a `(` as a "C" should be (using "crap" as the example):

```
\(rap
```