# filtering bad words from text

Tags: php, regex

This function filer the email from text and return matched pattern

```
  function parse($text, $words)
  {
    $resultSet = array();
    foreach ($words as $word){
      $pattern = 'regex to match emails';
      preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
      $this->pushToResultSet($matches);
    }
    return $resultSet;
  }
```

Similar way I want to match bad words from text and return them as `$resultSet`.

Here is code to filter badwords

[TEST HERE](http://ideone.com/f7uMZV)

```
$badwords = array('shit', 'fuck'); // Here we can use all bad words from database
$text = 'Man, I shot this f*ck, sh/t! fucking fu*ker sh!t f*cking  sh\t ;)';
echo "filtered words <br>";
echo $text."<br/>";
$words = explode(' ', $text);
foreach ($words as $word)
    {
        $bad= false;
        foreach ($badwords as $badword)
            {
                if (strlen($word) >= strlen($badword))
                {
                    $wordOk = false;
                    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($badword); $i++)
                    {   
                        if ($badword[$i] !== $word[$i] && ctype_alpha($word[$i]))
                        {
                            $wordOk = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!$wordOk)
                    {
                        $bad= true;
                        break;
                    }
        }
            }   
            echo $bad ? 'beep ' : ($word . ' '); // Here $bad words can be returned and replace with *. 
    }
```

Which replaces badwords with `beep`

But I want to push matched bad words to `$this->pushToResultSet()` and returning as in first code of email filtering.

can I do this with my bad filtering code?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/273516/1578604)

Comment: Let me share [this gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096634/regular-expression-preg-quote-symbols-are-not-detected/6099598#6099598) with you.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly converting David Atchley's answer to PHP, does this work as you want it to?

```
$blocked = array('fuck','shit','damn','hell','ass');
$text = 'Man, I shot this f*ck, damn sh/t! fucking fu*ker sh!t f*cking  sh\t ;)';
$matched = preg_match_all("/(".implode('|', $blocked).")/i", $text, $matches);
$filter = preg_replace("/(".implode('|', $blocked).")/i", 'beep', $text);
var_dump($filter);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Ha! Son of a gun, not sure why I did that in Javascript.  Late night.

Comment: Haha we've all been there :). At least now there's two solutions :P.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/datchley/rr3TG/) for working example.

Yes, you can match bad words (saving for later), replace them in the text and build the regex dynamically based on an array of bad words you're trying to filter (you might store it in DB, load from JSON, etc.).  Here's the main portion of the working example:

```
var blocked = ['fuck','shit','damn','hell','ass'],
    matchBlocked = new RegExp("("+blocked.join('|')+")", 'gi'),
    text = $('.unfiltered').text(),
    matched = text.match(matchBlocked),
    filtered = text.replace(matchBlocked, 'beep');
```

Please see the JSFiddle link above for the full working example.